# make center aligned content stay justified to the left in bootsrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have text in a card center but i want to make the text remain in the middle but along a straight on the left.
Here is the image of what i have.Below is what i want [image]

[image: Below is what i want]

I have **text center** class on the column containing the card that centers the text,But the are not on the same line.
here is the code.

```
<div class="container">
<p>Discover</p>
<hr >
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center" >
        <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-block ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <img class="thumbnail" src="./assets/images/foodposter.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Snail master</p>
                        <!-- <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 0.8em;">info_outline</i>In Food and Drink</p> -->
                        <p class="cardfont p-2">
                            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 1em;">today</i> 12 sept 2017</p>
                        <p class="cardfont p-2">
                            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 1em;">location_on</i>TRM,Thika Road</p>
                        <p class="cardfont p-2">
                            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 1em;">today</i> KSH.1200</p>
                        <p class="cardfont p-2">_</p>
                        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-2 " style="font-size: 0.8em;line-height: 80%;">Get Tickets</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" >
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <img class="thumbnail" src="./assets/images/comedyposter.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7">mate</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" >
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <img class="thumbnail" src="./assets/images/midnightposter.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7">mate</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>







</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your required html and css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest ways is to use **text-left** instead of **text-center** 
and give it a new class and margin it left and right equally to make it in centre

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
Image here
</div>
<div class="col-8 text-left">
<div class="xyz">
Snail master<br>
aaaaaa<br>
aaaaaaa
</div>
</div>

.xyz{
margin:0px 30px; as per your wish to make class in centre.
}
```

or you can use offset

Comment: I have added my custom margin seems to be working right now.Thank you